# Starting MediaPlayer from Timer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing a Battery Alarm App. and I want to play music using **media-player** in every one minute using the **Timer** and also want to repeat music 2 times within one minute.

This works fine for the first time when **Timer calls** the *8playAlarm() method** but after one minute when **Timer** again call the **playAlarm() method** it plays music only once.

```
     @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            mStartTime=preferencesAlert.getInt("alert",0);  // 0 == immediately
            mInterval=preferencesInterval.getInt("interval",1);  // 1==1 minute

            mSongUri=preferencesSongUri.getString("uri","android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/celesta");

            timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run () {
                    playAlarm();
                }
            };
            // schedule the task to run starting now and then every time interval...
            timer.schedule (hourlyTask,60000*mStartTime, 60000*mInterval);

    }
```

*playAlarm() method*

```
     private void playAlarm(){

            playerAlarm=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(mSongUri));
            playerAlarm.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    repeatMax=preferencesRepeat.getInt("repeat",2);

                    if(repeatMin<=repeatMax){
                        repeatMin++;

                        if(playerAlarm!=null && !playerAlarm.isPlaying()) {
                            mp.seekTo(0);
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    }else {
                        mp.reset();
                        mp.release();
                    }
                }
            });
            playerAlarm.start();
        }
```

I want to play music two times in every minute but it plays only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first time works because your `repeatMin` is still at its first value but after you did not set it at 0 again in your code

```
repeatMin = first int value; // you have to reinitialize your repeatMin somewhere when the sound 
                 has been played for the second time
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess because you are executing method in onCreate which calls only once. Might be you can make it in some background service and call it every minute